# asp.net mvc Jquery client side validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a strange problem.

while MicrosoftMvcValidation works in my mvc project, MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation doesn't.

this is my code:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thank you

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485326/jquery-validation-without-requiring-ms-scripts-in-asp-net-mvc2-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:
It apears that inorder to use the asp.net mvc's client validation you have to use the labda expression text and validation formats (Html.TextBoxFor and Html.ValidationMessageFor)
thank you