# How can I add callbacks to jquery validation (when used in MVC 2)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery for validation in my MVC2 web app ([**as described here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485326/jquery-validation-without-requiring-ms-scripts-in-asp-net-mvc2-project)) and I'd like to wire up some callbacks that the jquery validation plugin supports, like [**invalidHandler**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), etc.

I can manually edit the [**MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js**](http://code.google.com/p/productinfo/source/browse/trunk/src/ProductInfoMVC/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js?spec=svn10&r=10) and add my callbacks (in __MVC_EnableClientValidation, in the options variable) but I was looking for a better approach since that file is used repeatedly and I don't want to have to create one-off copies.

A way to manually add an invalidHandler (etc) callback to the form validation, would be exactly what I need.  Obviously this would normally be done via the options when calling validate() for the first time, but since Microsoft controls that particular part, that isnt an option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [**Herikstad.net**](http://www.herikstad.net/2010/04/add-invalidhandler-after-jquery.html):

> If you have a problem where you need
>   to add the option `invalidHandler` to
>   your jqueryValidate (jQuery Validation
>   Plugin) after it has been initialized,
>   this is how it can be done:
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>     $("#contactForm").bind('invalid-form.validate',
>
>         function(form, validator) {
>             alert('validation failed!');
>         }
>     );
> });
> ```
>
> Regularly you would add this on
>   initialization:
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>     $('#contactForm').validate({
>         invalidHandler: 
>         function(form, validator) {
>             alert('validation failed!');
>         }, 
>         rules: {}
>     });
> });
> ```
>
> Note: invalidHandler will be called
>   when validation of form fails on
>   submit (e.g. values for a field is
>   missing or such).
>
> This might work for other options of
>   the jqueryValidate plugin, but I'm not
>   sure which property to use. I found
>   the property to bind to in the
>   jquery.validate.js file, you might
>   want to look there.