# How to detect that unobtrusive validation has been successful?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I have this code that triggers when a form is submitted:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById("Address").value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            $("#LatitudeLongitude").val(results[0].geometry.location);
            $("form").submit();
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
    $('form').unbind('submit');
    return false;
});
```

What it does: it calls google geocoding service to translate an address into latitude/longitude which is set into a hidden field of the form. If there is a result, then the form is submitted.

The problem is that if validation fails (for instance a required field has not been set) then the call to geocoding is still made. Moreover, if I click a second time on the submit button, even if the required field has not been set, the form is posted.

How can I call the geocoding service only if the unobtrusive validation has been successful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than attaching to the `submit()` event, you need to capture an earlier event, and exercise control over how to proceed.

First, let's assume your original button has an id of `submit` and you create a new submit button with an id of `startSubmit`.  Then, hide the original submit button by setting the HTML attribute `display="false"`.  Next, bind to the `click` event of your new button, and add your code, as modified:

```
$("#startSubmit").live("click", function() {
    // check if the form is valid
    if ($("form").validate().form()) {
        // valid, proceed with geocoding
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = $("#Address").val();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                $("#LatitudeLongitude").val(results[0].geometry.location);
            } 
            else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
            // proceed to submit form
            $("#submit").click();
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

This will invoke validation, so that geocoding will only occur if the form is valid, then, after geocoding has returned a response, it will submit the form by incoking the click event on the submit button.

Comment: A pity that it needs 2 buttons, but it seems the way to go. Thx.

Comment: At least ony one button will show.  If this was helpful, please mark as answered. Thanks.

Comment: Please could you update to reflect that `live` was depreciated as of jQuery 1.7 and use `on` instead? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I implemented something similar (with thanks to cousellorben), in my case I wanted to disable and change the text of the submit button but only on success. Here's my example:

```
$("#btnSubmit").live("click", function() {
    if ($("form").validate().form()) {
        $(this).val("Please Wait...").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("form").submit();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

The only difference is that my example uses a single button.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873534/how-can-i-add-callbacks-to-jquery-validation-when-used-in-mvc-2) may help you, it gives a quick example of how a function is called when the form is invalid, based on the use of JQuery Validate, which is what MVC uses.